# Can the Gauss-Bonnet theorem be proven from Stokes's theorem?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, stokes-theorem

In a comment to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913959/relationship-between-stokess-theorem-and-the-gauss-bonnet-theorem), John Ma claims that the Gauss-Bonnet theorem can be proven from Stokes's theorem, but does not explain how.

For two dimensions, Stokes's theorem says that for any smooth 2-manifold (i.e. surface) $S$ and one-form $\omega$ defined on $S$,

$$\oint_{\partial S} \omega = \iint_S d\omega.$$

I could vaguely imagine coming up with some kind of one-form $\omega$ that depends on the metric, such that (a) along the boundary curve $\omega$ maps the boundary tangent vector to the geodesic curvature and (b) in the surface interior $\ast d\omega$ equals the Gaussian curvature. (In more concrete vector-field language, this corresponds to a vector field $\vec{\omega}$ defined over the surface such that (a) on the boundary curve $\vec{\omega} \cdot d\vec{l}$ equals the curve's geodesic curvature and (b) in the surface interior $(\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{\omega}) \cdot d\vec{S}$ equals the Gaussian curvature.) This would reproduce part of the Gauss-Bonnet formula, but how could you possibly get out the Euler characteristic term?

Comment: The proof given by Chern in "A simple intrinsic proof of the Gauss-Bonnet formula for closed Riemannian manifolds" is based on Stokes' theorem.

Comment: For the 2-dimensional G-B theorem, you can see (most of) the argument on p. 105 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf). The local-to-global argument to get to $\chi(M)$ is the standard triangulation argument. If you recognize $\chi$ as the sum of the indices of a vector field, you can turn the proof into a direct argument, taking out little balls $B$ around each zero and seeing that $\int_{\partial B} \bar\omega_{12}$ gives the index of the vector field.

Answer (score 5):

See [Differential Forms and Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540576185) (by [Manfredo P. Do Carmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manfredo_do_Carmo) ) chapter 6 section 1. The proof of Gauss-Bonnet's Theorem presented by Do Carmo in his text is essentially the same as given by [S.S. Chern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiing-Shen_Chern) and use the Stokes' theorem. The original proof of S.S. Chern is found [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969302?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Comment: Could you gist it for me? I don't have access to the book or the paper.

Comment: @tparker I only have access to the Portuguese version of the Do Carmo book I bought recently.

Comment: For paper see the link. https://scholar.google.com.br/scholar?hl=pt-BR&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=A+Simple+Intrinsic+Proof+of+the+Gauss-Bonnet+Formula+for+Closed+Riemannian+Manifolds&btnG=

Comment: I'm afraid this proof is too advanced for me to understand :(